# Javascript - Add styles to input class type checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying to input style elements into a input class checkbox. a Remember me checkbox to be exact. I dont know why this code wouldn't work? do i have to write some code like appendChild(...) to create a style element inside the html first or what?

```js
       RememberMe.document.getElementById('rememberme');
      RememberMe.style.marginRight="-90px";
      RememberMe.style.marginLeft="-90px";
```

```css
element.style {
EMPTY, i want to insert CSS to this element that wont affect any other elements.
}
```

```html
<label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox inline">
     <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"> <span>Kom ihåg mig</span>
    </label>
```

Comment: I think `RememberMe.document.getElementById('rememberme');` should be `RememberMe = document.getElementById('rememberme');`

Comment: When asking questions about why something doesn't work, it's important to do some research, and include any error messages you might be getting. For instance, if you click on "Run code snippet" in your question, an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: RememberMe is not defined" shows at the bottom of the results.

Comment: my bad, i didnt realise i had rememberme.document but actually what i was doing in my code was exactly what you described, but it still didn't work somehow. But i ended up doing it with css only. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: If all you want to do is add some style to that specific element is there a reason you are doing it with javascript? You could use plain CSS by adding this into your style tag:

```
#rememberme {
    margin-left: "-90px";
    margin-right: "-90px";
}
```

Otherwise you could use jQuery to add the CSS style properties:

```
$('#rememberme').css({"margin-left": "-90px", "margin-right": "-90px"})
```

This one line would replace these three lines of javascript:

```
var RememberMe = document.getElementById('rememberme');
RememberMe.style.marginRight="-90px";
RememberMe.style.marginLeft="-90px";
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i ended up doing it by CSS. I just wanted it to be different depending on if you had javascript enabled or not, but in the end your code works great!

Comment: @MuppetShovel  The best way to say "Thanks for answer" is to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your first line should probably be `var RememberMe=document.getElementById('rememberme');`